# Как может существовать одновремено две верхних/нижних границы у множества?

Tags: математика

Читаю определение в вики:

> Точной (наименьшей) верхней гранью (границей), или супре́мумом (лат. supremum — самый высокий) подмножества {\displaystyle X} X упорядоченного множества (или класса) {\displaystyle M} M, называется наименьший элемент {\displaystyle M} M, который равен или больше всех элементов множества {\displaystyle X} X. Другими словами, супремум — это наименьшая из всех верхних граней. Обозначается {\displaystyle \sup X} \sup X.

Но как может быть несколько верхних граней одновременно?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Читайте внимательнее определение верхней (и нижней) границы. Например, для множества `{ 1, 2, 3 }` значения `3`, `42`, `100500` являются *верхними границами*. 
И таких верхних границ можно напридумывать бесконечно много. *Точной* верхней границей является только `3`.